# Can a div be partially transparent in cfdocument pdfs? How?

Tags: css, html, coldfusion, cfdocument

Need a div to partially show the image behind it, is this even possible? Tried:

```
opacity:.5;
```

AND

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
```

Both produce a solid div.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about cfdocument, but have you tried `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`?

Comment: @Demian Brecht: Thanks for the idea but still gives me a solid div.

Comment: Did you try using a semi-transparent `.png`?

Comment: @thirtydot: arg, sometimes it's the simple hacks. That accomplishes what I need. Please supply it as an answer to I can give you your well deserved rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a wondrous pure guess in a comment, I managed to find a working answer:

> Did you try using a semi-transparent
>   `.png`?

Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Right you are, thirtydot!  You gotta toss a thumbs-up for cfdocument, eh?

I've confirmed this works in CF9.  I do wonder whether this example is backward compatible.
Can anyone confirm other ColdFusion versions support this?

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" pagetype="letter" 
    margintop="0.5" marginbottom="0.5" 
    marginleft="0.5" marginright="0.5">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { background-image: url( "images/use_your_image.jpg" ); }

    img { border: 3px solid #990000; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Does transparent image appear above the background repeated image?
    <img src="images/red_transparent_100x100.png">
    <!--- Generated this at http://transparent-png-generator.com/ --->
</body>
</html>

</cfdocument>
```

Comment: I was using CF7 at the time of my question and had no problems using the semi-transparent .png