# Why is PDF created by CFDocument blank?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, itext, cfdocument

I have CFDocument generating a PDF. When the PDF opens, I can briefly see it as it should be. Then it disappears. Visibly gone anyway because I can find one of the images by clicking around, right click on it, copy it out and past it into an image editor. So the content is there but not visible. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Do you have a small repro case?

Comment: Not really. There is a possibility of server differences. Only happening on live, can't reproduce on dev.

Comment: Is it all pdf's or only some? Major or minor version difference?

Comment: It's anything I try to create with a recent code release. AFAICT existing pdf generation is still functioning fine.

Comment: I do not know how your pdf processes differ. But without a lot to go on, I would start by looking at what is in your code release that affects pdfs? Also, check your patch levels on dev vs prod.

Comment: what type of content is in your PDF? It sounds like you have images - try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109183/image-not-displayed-in-cfdocument

Comment: Hm.. I thought the issue was a different than a broken image link. But I could be wrong ;)

Comment: @invertedSpear - I noticed this thread of yours about transparency. Stupid question, but any chance this might be the cause ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065635/can-a-div-be-partially-transparent-in-cfdocument-pdfs-how

Comment: yeah problem isn't broken picture links, it's just that there is nothing visible in the PDF, like I said you can still copy stuff if you know where to right-click, and you can highlight text that isn't visibly there and copy that. Also the transparency issue is with other PDFs not in use yet on our live system, so shouldn't be involved. Thanks for the help guys, probably going to shelf this till our ops guy gets back from vacation so he can analyze the differences between live and dev.

Comment: @invertedSpear - Okay, that was a stab in the dark anyway ;) It does sound like a problem in the release. Hopefully your ops guy returns soon so you get things sorted out.

Comment: can you share the code that you have in the cfdocument call?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, this turned out to be a server issue. Sys Admin had to do a file by file comparison of the .jar files to determine where the difference was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case this turned out to be a difference between servers. I guess there was a stealth update to CF7 that we picked up on one server and not the other. By stealth I mean that there were two hotfixes issued with the same ID that were different. To fix this our Sys Admin did a file by file comparison of all the CF .jar files and found what needed to be applied.